# What is the tensordot of this 4D einsum operation?

Tags: python, numpy, tensordot

Here's a simple code that "batch multiplies" a 4D matrix a by 3D matrix b:

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from operator import mul

def einsum(a, b):
    return np.einsum('ijkl,jkl->ikl', a, b)

def original(a, b):
    s0, s1, s2, s3 = a.shape
    c = np.empty((s0, s2, s3))
    for j in range(s3):
        for i in range(s2):
            c[:, j, i] = np.dot(a[:, :, j, i], b[:, j, i])
    return c

sz_a = (16, 4, 512, 512)
sz_b = (4, 512, 512)

a = np.random.random(reduce(mul, sz_a)).reshape(sz_a)
b = np.random.random(reduce(mul, sz_b)).reshape(sz_b)
```

For timing:

```
%timeit original(a, b)
395 ms ± 2.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit einsum(a, b)
23.1 ms ± 191 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I'd like to test out tensordot's performance to see how it compares, but I'm really having some trouble wrapping my ahead around how to use it here. If anyone is familiar enough to guide me with this, it would greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My original thought was:

```
np.tensordot(a, b, axes=((1),(0)))
```

But that gives me a MemoryError so I don't think that's right...

Comment: There isn't an equivalent.  You are doing a `dot` on the first 2 dimensions (sum on the `j`), while the last 2 come-along-for-the-ride.   `tensordot` does an outer product with extra dimensions like that.  If it didn't produce the memory error, you'd still have to throw away most of the values with a `diag`.  With some transposing you might be able to do this with `matmul`.

Comment: Your `a` expression can simply be written as `a = np.random.random(sz_a)` - `random` accepts a shape tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Time comparisons of your `einsum` with a `matmul` equivalent:

```
In [910]: timeit (a.transpose(2,3,0,1)@b[:,None].transpose(2,3,0,1)).transpose(2,3,0,1)[:
     ...: ,0]
90.5 ms ± 92.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [911]: timeit np.einsum('ijkl,jkl->ikl', a, b)
92.7 ms ± 2.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Times are close enough that I suspect `einsum` optimization is actually using `matmul`.  Originally `einsum` used its own compiled sum-of-products iteration, but recent with recent changes it uses a variety of methods, including `dot` and `matmul` if they fit.

`matmul` was created to handle the case where the initial dimensions represent a stack of matrices.  In your problem the last 2 dimensions are this stack, with the `dot` acting on the initial.  `matmul` was created to handle this kind of stacked dots.  `dot`, and its derivative `tensordot` don't handle that kind of stacking.